# Accessing IndexedDB from outside the browser

Tags: indexeddb

Is it possible to access IndexedDB from outside the browser, or from outside the domain that created it?

I'm thinking about the case of storing data to some IndexedDB related to some specific domain, as it is always the case, then gaining access to that data, or migrating it to another domain, after the first domain ceases to exist or ceases to be reliable.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible for security reasons. Only the website that created the IndexedDB instance can read or modify the data. [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Security) In order to achieve something like this, you would need to upload the data from the client to your server, store that data, and then send that data back to the clients machine from the new domain.

What you're trying to achieve sounds a bit fishy. There's no easy, reliable way to do what you're wanting because there probably aren't many legitimate use cases.

Comment: The use case is something like a website that works as a platform for manipulating data in IndexedDB (its own IndexedDB, the secure normal way). So the user would access that website, do stuff with his own data using the website's Javascript/HTML interface, then go to sleep.

On the other day the user would do the same, and again and again. The data will be saved in his own computer, everything will be fine.

But then, someday, the website will be down. Is all his data lost forever?

Comment: Why not use a server side database that doesn't have the restrictions of a local DB?

Comment: From the point of view of the user, that server can still someday disappear with his data such as the webpage, so there's no advantage.

Comment: If you place the data on your server, then yes, the server could "disappear" one day. If you place the data on the user's computer other things could happen: the user could inadvertently delete their indexeddb data, their harddrive could crash, they could lose their device, their browser installation could become corrupted and have to be reinstalled possibly deleting their data, they could need to access their data from a different (or public) computer, etc, etc. Hosting the users' data on a server is quite advantageous.

Comment: Well, I know I can place the data on the server, I just want that some data be kept with the clients, so they can be responsible for it. Is that too crazy for you?

Comment: One solution to your problem can be providing an offline application or offline version of the site which has the same domain of your website by storing some html documents using appcaches.The data remains accessible through this offline version even when the user is not connected to net or site goes down. The data will however not be available if user clears the browser cache